# another term for " 'international' hotel"

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms, paraphrasing

I have an article which informs the readers that our company [a local provider] helped a "foreign hotel". This "foreign hotel" is not an international hotel.

My original article title:

**A Local Provider Has Extended Help To An International Hotel**

The article title is a bit misleading because the hotel is not "international", what is
the appropriate title for this replacing the 'International Hotel'?

Comment: *Foreign* and *international* are not much related. If the company is from outside the country, *foreign* is correct and nothing odd about it. If you mean a *multinational* you can use that adjective instead. However, *hotel* is not the word here: the hotel itself cannot be foreign or international but the company could be. So maybe a 'foreign hospitality **firm** ' or something on those lines.

Comment: Nice to be of help. Here on ELU, we just up vote a comment/ answer to show it is useful, no need to say thanks.

Comment: "International hotel chain" is a reasonably well-used phrase in English, or just international chain.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the most natural way to say this would be to say where, exactly, the hotel is.

> How a Local Business Helped Out a Canadian Hotel

expresses the information you want to get across--the fact that the hotel was in a foreign country--perfectly well. Unless there's some good reason not to include the specific country or continent in the title, including it is the simplest way to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The hotel is located in Papua New Guinea. I am not sure if it still sounds good.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest "a Melanesian hotel" or "a South Pacific hotel."

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use **foreign owned** hotel. This makes it clear that the ownership is foreign, while not sounding xenophobic, and not confusing it with an international hotel.

Comment: Excuse the ignorance, but what exactly is an 'international hotel'?

Comment: @WS2 That is a hotel that exists in two or more nations, I'm surprised you didn't know that.

Comment: "international hotel" is meaningless and a strange construct.  it would mean a hotel building built on a border, so the hotel would be .. an international hotel.

Comment: international [AHD]: 1. Of, relating to, or involving two or more nations: an international commission; international affairs.
2. Extending across or transcending national boundaries >> WS2 is quite correct. The string is ill-defined, and Frank's suggestion leads to the comical situation Joe Blow describes. His 'international hotel chain' (above) string makes far more sense.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The Arbez Hotel in La Cure is an _international hotel_. I was sure there was one in England & Scotland but I can't find any reference to it. There is nothing wrong with _international hotel_.

Comment: @Frank So if _you_ only know of one (on the border between France and Switzerland), why should WS2 know about it? _I_ didn't; the more likely scenario is that any writer of 'international hotel' really means (and should use) 'hotel which is part of an international chain' (or the 'International Hotel' if the owners called it that). 'I'm surprised you didn't know that' is dismissive.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth WS2 asked `what exactly is an 'international hotel'` I was surprised he didn't know that it would be `a hotel that exists in two or more nations`. I'm not at all surprised that he didn't know that there is at least one that meets that definition.

Comment: @Frank Can you tell me what is normally meant by an 'international school', without looking it up in Wikipedia? 'International' is highly polysemic, and one just can't assume a particular sense (existing in two or more nations / promoting international education / representing different nations / in some way relating to two or more nations) in any particular expression.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes I can - an international school is normally a school where the native language takes second place to (usually) English and the students are (usually) a mix of natives and foreigners, but that has little to do with an _international hotel_.

Comment: @Frank 'The Tirana International Hotel is an international hotel located between the central Skanderbeg Square and the Zogu I Boulevard in central Tirana, Albania.' [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tirana_International_Hotel) confirms WS2's implied claims about the ambiguity of the descriptor. As does 'Our client is an international hotel and they are looking for an Experienced Chef to join their team.' [Melbourne, Australia]. And I'm finding many more instances of this sense than 'straddling two countries'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm not sure a Wikipedia entry about a hotel defines the word _international_ but I did notice that the "Google auto definition" https://www.google.com/webhp?q=define+international when expanded does include "used by people of many nations" (with no source) but that would mean that the London Tube Network was 'international' and the toilets in my house could be described as 'international'. ;)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you for your efforts in my absence to defend the fact that the term 'international hotel' lacks clarity. This discussion has, at least, informed me that a hotel exists which straddles two countries, something of which I was in total ignorance until now! And what a fascinating history the Hotel Arbez has. But noting that one suite has the bed in one country and bathroom in t'other, it leaves me wondering if you have to show your passport if you get up in the night to relieve yourself.

Comment: @WS2 Doubtless. And then pull the 'International hotel chain' Joe Blow so thoughtfully provides. I'm surprised the Marx Brothers didn't plunder this rich vein.